# How to pass PickerValue in URL in iphone

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, nsurl

```
arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];             //pickerview radius array
//[arrayNo addObject:@" Radius "];

[arrayNo addObject:@" 10 "];
[arrayNo addObject:@" 15000 "];
[arrayNo addObject:@" 20000 "];
[pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
[addressField resignFirstResponder];
radius.text= [arrayNo objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

I want to pass the above radius picker in following url at radius

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://.............../phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=%f&lng=%f&radius=%f",lati,longi,radius];
```

I tried with following code on button click event but not working.

```
NSString * radius = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",[arrayNo objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]]autorelease];
```

What code should I write for the same...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code to,

```
float radius = [arrayNo objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://.............../phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=%f&lng=%f&radius=%f",lati,longi,radius];
```

And, you don't need the last line `NSString * radius = ...`.

Comment: thanks for the code. But above code is passing value at "lng" parameter instead of radius. How can I set this???